# Inbox button with html css

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a project in which I want to give an inbox button which should look like a Facebook inbox button.
How can I do that with HTML/CSS?

I tried to search it but I can not get the accuracy.
The only way I got to do is to assign a background image to the button or link.

I am unable to do that.
Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

This is the HTML code which I found when I searched for it

And CSS is

```
img{
 width:25px ;
 height:25px;
 border:0px;
}
p{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:35px;
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: there are plenty of icons available in the wild, like http://fontawesome.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use fontawesome.

Add the code you recieve in your email to the `<head>`
http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Then you can add any icon from fontawesome into your page
http://fontawesome.io/icon/facebook-official/

e.g.    `<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Control the look and color as you would text.

Comment: Thomas, can u explain it more please?

Comment: Use the form in the /get-started/ link and add that to the head of your website. This then allows you to put the <i class=""> code into your site where it can pull in all sorts of icons.

Comment: Thank you Thomas
May God bless you

Comment: No Worries. Please help by up voting. Thanks